# React: onClick on button not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

For the past hour, I have been trying to get this to work.
onClick on any of the buttons is not working at all… What am I doing wrong?

```
const React = require('react');

class Questionnaire extends React.Component {
constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { selectedSection: 0 };
}

selectSection (e) {
    console.log(e);
}

render () {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className='btn-group mr-2' role='group'>
                <button className='btn btn-primary' onClick={this.selectSection}>A</button>
                <button className='btn btn-secondary' onClick={this.selectSection}>B</button>
                <button className='btn btn-secondary' onClick={this.selectSection}>C</button>
                <button className='btn btn-secondary' onClick={this.selectSection}>D</button>
          </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}

 module.exports = Questionnaire;
```

I should mention that I am using it with express-react-views

Comment: Are there any console errors?

Comment: No console errors

Comment: The code seems to be working fine for me. Nothing's showing up on your end?

Comment: Yeah! No logs when I click on any of the buttons.

Comment: From express-react-views readme: "It renders static markup and *does not* support mounting those views on the client." https://github.com/reactjs/express-react-views/issues/59

Comment: Thanks CD..
How do I work around it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the function to the component like so:

```
class Questionnaire extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { selectedSection: 0 };

        this.selectSection = this.selectSection.bind(this)
    }
```

Keep everything else the same

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
    const React = require('react');

    class Questionnaire extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { selectedSection: 0 };
    }

    selectSection = function(e){
    console.log(e);
  }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className='btn-group mr-2' role='group'>
                    <button className='btn btn-primary' onClick={this.selectSection}>A</button>
                    <button className='btn btn-secondary' onClick={this.selectSection}>B</button>
                    <button className='btn btn-secondary' onClick={this.selectSection}>C</button>
                    <button className='btn btn-secondary' onClick={this.selectSection}>D</button>
              </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
    }
```

Comment: What's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the method to the class. Add this line to the constructor:

`this.selectSection = this.selectSection.bind(this);`