# React HTML button created in function does not register click event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an App.js which calls a function `DisplayQuestions` in its render method. What is the right place to declare the `handleClick()` function? I tried to declare it inside of DisplayQuestions but that never seems to get called. I looked at [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45682119/1634753) but couldnt get the binding working like this question, possibly because the DisplayQuestions component is a function (not part of App.js).

The button displays fine, but clicks are never logged to console. I have tried creating the button using the event property and the onclick property with the same result:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App"></div>
          <DisplayQuestions />
    )
  }
```

DisplayQuestions:

```
export function DisplayQuestions() {
    const [notes, setNotes] = useState([{ questions: [], definition: "" }]);
    const [query, setNotesQuery] = useState("Dynamo");
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    //handleClick function
    var handleClick = (q) => {
        console.log(`handleClick`, q)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            setIsLoading(true);
            setNotes(await NotesApiQuery(query))
            setIsLoading(false);
        };
        fetchData();
    }, [query]);

    return (
        <div>
            {isLoading ? (
                <div> Loading ...</div>
            ) :
                <div>
                    <h3>Notes({notes.length}):</h3>
                    {
                        notes.map((n) => (
                            <div>
                                <li>
                                    <span style={{ visibility: 'hidden' }} id={n.questions}>{n.definition}</span>
                                    <button event={handleClick(n.questions)}>Show/Hide ans</button>
                                </li>
                            </div>
                        )
                        )
                    }
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: That `App` code won't compile. JSX doesn't allow multiple top-level elements.

Comment: *"This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback"* That's for class components, not functional components using hooks.

Comment: The first hit when I google: *react button click* is https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html and it has a short example above the fold. `<button onClick={activateLasers}>
  Activate Lasers
</button>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not hooking up the function correctly, and you have extra code you've probably put there because you saw it in class components. But yours is a functional component, not a class component.

Here's how to hook it up correctly:

```
<button onClick={() => handleClick(n.questions)}>Show/Hide ans</button>
```

Note that uses `onClick`, not `event`, and wraps the call to `handleClick(n.questions)` in an arrow function.

Then remove this statement and the comment above it: `this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);`

Answer (score 0):

you can try binding like below

```
<button onclick={()=>handleClick(n.questions)}>Show/Hide ans</button>
```

Comment: `button` has no `event` property. The user would also need to change that to `onClick` (as in my answer).